# Not getting SoapAction attribute in WCF service Request Header

Tags: asp.net, wcf

i tried to get SoapAction value from WCF Request Header.

In WSDL file, SoapAtion is mentioned as below

```
<wsdl:operation name="getCustomer">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getCustomer" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="ServiceFaultExceptionFault">
        <soap:fault use="literal" name="ServiceFaultExceptionFault" namespace="" />
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

but, I am getting below Request Header from `((HttpWebRequest)request).Headers`  object

```
Request Header:
{
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Host: testhub.gct.com
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:4ecd5f66-38c2-4c8d-b360-b166d19d91a5
Request-Id: |k6/8Z.Pads2.8cfbcce5_10.
Content-Length: 1138
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
}
```

I am missing SoapAction attribute value here, can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Seems you are missing it. Only the sender can (or should) actually insert it. What do you expect us to do about it? Did you ask the sender why they don't send it?

Comment: i am consuming this wcf service, and required to log operation name in the application insight

Comment: So *you* are the sender?

Comment: yes, i passed this from wsdl file, but same is not showing in Request Header